# Taylor series for arcsin(x), incorrect output C language

Tags: c, trigonometry, calculus, taylor-series

I wrote a program that gets from the user a value x and an integer n, the program then prints arcsin(x) using the taylor serie for arcsin
http://tedmuller.us/Math/img/Taylor-arcsin.gif

but for some reason its not working. when i enter x=1 i get an output of 1.19 rather than pi/2.

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,n;
    double x,sum,last;
    printf("Please enter the x you wish to calculate arcsin(x) for \n");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("Enter n\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    last=x;
    sum=last;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        last*=((x*x)*(2*i-1))/((2*i)*(2*i+1));
        sum+=last;
    }
    printf("arcsin(%lf) = %lf",x,sum);
    getch();
}
```

basic idea is this: last and sum both start with value of x. then i advance last to be the next number in the serie, add it to sum, advance last again, add to sum...rinse and repeat n times.

Comment: What value are you entering for `n`?  How quickly does that series converge in general?  Have you printed out the terms (`last` values) as your go?  Why not?

Comment: I'm entering quite a large value of n, 10. So the answer should be very accurate, even if i input an n of 100 the answer wont differ much.

Comment: And there's no real point in printing the value of last, since the value of last at any given point, is just a part of the answer, its not the answer itself

Comment: Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: @OriaGruber: You also have a mistake in your expansion.  Write down the terms you're generating and you'll see they don't match the taylor series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a mistake in your expansion.

Try this:
`last*=((x*x)*(2*i-1)*(2*i-1))/((2*i)*(2*i+1))`

You'll still need lots of terms.  With 1000 terms I get `arcsin(1.0) ~= 1.552963` . ( Your code 1.194958 )

10000 terms `arcsin(1.0) ~= 1.565155`. ( Your code 1.194958 )

Comment: you multiplied by 2i-1 twice, why??

Comment: @OriaGruber: To cancel the constant from the previous term.  Stare some more at the series, you have a mistake.  Your code adds two constant factors to the denominator for every term, the series only has one.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that that series converges logarithmically quickly when x=1.  Notice that x=1 is at the boundary of arcsin's radius of convergence.  So it's not surprising that you'll get extremely slow convergence.

A bigger problem is that you didn't actually implement the series you thought you had implemented.  You're summing something that converges linearly.  It looks like it might be the integral of something well-knkown, but it's certainly not arcsin.

Comment: I understand the part of the convergence and 1 being the boundary of arcsin, I'm okay with that. But can you please explain why the series i calculated isnt the one of arcsin? i look at the formula, and I look at my algorithm, and I can't see the difference. also for all other values (where |x|<1) i get a correct answer for arcsinx

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series you expanded has six-place accuracy for `|x| < .5`, five-place for `|x| < .6`, four-place for `|x| < .7`, three-place for `|x| < .8`, and two-place for `|x| < .9`.

Of course, there's no reason to think the Taylor polynomial is the best
polynomial of a given degree. Welcome to Numerical Analysis.

It takes too many terms to get a good estimation for `|x| = 1`, because the derivative of arcsin(x) has a pole at `x = 1`, so that *its* Taylor series converges very slowly. This means the Taylor expansion is not an efficient way of approximating arcsin(x) except for small x. If you printed each term of the expansion as you calculate it, you'd see it's extremely small to make the series converge in a reasonable amount of time.

For your aid,  Milton Abramowitz and Irene Stegun in their book "*Handbook of Mathematical Functions*", p.81 derive this approximation formula:

```
arcsin(x) = pi/2 - sqrt(1 - x)(a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3)
```

where

```
a0 = 1.5707288
a1 = -0.2121144
a2 = 0.0742610
a3 = -0.0187293
```

which performs much better near 1.